# COM Interop issue in IIS - object creation failing

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, com, interop

I am consuming an activex/com object (generated by Unify Vision application) in one of my asp.net application. I am getting the following error.

System.InvalidCastException: Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {9C2D0002-3A17-11E0-8000-FC9865BE5C68} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 80004002.

I tried the following approaches

1. I tried to consume the activex/com object in console application. There I am able to create the object and got the result (though the app is hanging after that)
2. If I run the asp.net app in visual studio with built in web server (casino) and file system as the option(without deploying it to IIS) , it's working.
3. But when I deploy it to IIS,it's failing. Even I tried impersonation , registry permissions and gave aspnet account/iis launcher account the admin privileges.
   But no use. I tried unistalling and reinstalling of the activex/com object but nothing is working.

I am currently running out of ideas. Please help.

Thanks,
sveerap

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in DllGetClassObject for your COM dll, does that breakpoint hit? What about your object's constructor?

Comment: The COM is a third party component and is not written by us. I am not sure of ' DllGetClassObject' method though. Is it something that we can write over the COM?. I have added the com as reference in my project and using it just like other .net component

Comment: DllGetClassObject is part of how a DLL exposes a COM object. If this is a 3rd party COM component does the component vendor supply a debug version or sources?

Comment: The vendor didn't provide a debug version

Answer (score 1):

Your COM component may require an STA thread to run on.  Try starting up an STA thread and running the code on there.  Just to test.

Comment: Yes, that's the most likely reason.

Comment: I added the attribute AspCompat="true" to @page directive but still got the same error

Comment: A quick Internet search yield the following promising articles: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163544.aspx and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308095

Comment: I am running under STA thread only . Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState is returning it as STA and i am creating the object on page load. I even tried running the app pool under local system account but no use